# Is it possible to create additional function keys?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, function-keys

I have seen some laptops in the past that had a keyboard without a numpad and some numpad keys over some letter keys accessible with the fn key. Like this :

[image]

I happen to have a keyboard without these keys, would it be possible to manually add them, as in configure my system so that when I press fn + J it undestands it as if Numpad 1 key was pressed.

And more generally, I would be interested to know if it's possible to create fn keys that have a more special behaviour like the brightness control or music players's play/pause buttons.

I have been doing some searches and got nowhere, I have no idea where to look.

### Edit:

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS standard installation

Comment: You have given no OS & release details. On my own system I'd look to use the "*Shortcut keys*" functions in config, possibly even refining then directly via the .conf file as I find it easier to understand than the GUI tool. The GUI tool can be handy to set the keystroke you want though. Specifics as to your OS, release & desktop though matter.

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (post edited as well)

Comment: I think this is a firmware function, not a X11 or GNU/Linux thing. On my Lenovo laptop (with Fn/Ctrl keys swapped) Fn shows up as keycode 151 in `xev`. Maybe you could use that to define a new level and have 'm' map to '0' in that level.